# Python 3.11.6 module not found on Fedora 38 GNOME

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I just updated my system on Fedora 38 GNOME. I tried to launch Python from a terminal. When I enter:

```
import Tkinter
```

I get a `Module not Found` error message. `Tkinter 3.11` is present on the system. Has anyone run into this problem? Thanks for any help with this!

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive, so you should use:

```
import tkinter
```

Instead of:

```
import Tkinter
```

Comment: Just as a note, `Tkinter` is for python 2 and `tkinter` is for python 3.